# How many battle droid units were created for the Second Battle of Geonosis?

Tags: star-wars

In the episode "Weapons Factory" from Season Two of Star Wars The Clone Wars, the Tactical droid TX-21 informs Lord Archduke Poggle the Lesser that there are 10 new garrisons of battle droids armed and ready for battle.

How many battle droids are composed within a single garrison, then times ten for ten garrisons?

I imagine in my mind (but I have no canon to support this) that one droid garrison is somewhere between 100,000 droids to 1,000,000 for each garrison.

Comment: The best I can find is Wookieepedia's Legends article on the [Separatist Droid Army](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Separatist_Droid_Army), which supposedly had "over a million" B1s, 100k B2s, and 3k droidekas...but that was for the *First* Battle of Geonosis. I suppose you could say that there were probably a comparable number of droids (if not more) for the Second Battle.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Odds - According to this EU story, they were building a million droids a year per factory. That puts the number into the tens of millions at least.

Answer (score 2):

Well I can speculate based on some numbers, but there is no concrete numbers for this. 
In the Attack of The Clones on Kamino Lama Su (a Kaminoan) says:

> Two hundred thousand
>   units are ready, with another
>   million well on the way.

So at the time of the first battle for Geonosis The droid armies were outnumbered by only an army of 200,000 clones at the most. Examining the droid army we see they have the planet carrier ships (the big ball looking things trying to take off), each of which contains an invasion army. I'd imagine that one of those could be a "garrison" at least. So 200,000 clones vs 5 or so garrisons of droids resulted in the droids retreating quickly. So if we operate under the assumption a planetship sontains roughly 1 garrison I would make an educated guess and say the number of droids in a "garrison" would be around 50,000 droids.

EDIT: I'm assuming that the structure of the droid armies is similar during the second battle of Geonosis. If you consider the fact that clones take a very long time to make ( I read they had a production rate of about 1.8 mil/year http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsglossaryandfaq/a/Star-Wars-Faq-How-Many-Clone-Troopers-Are-There.htm) , and the second for Geonosis was in the same year, so there was not a lot of time to produce more droids or clones, they did not have many more clones available at the time. So considering this matchup, I think that it is fair to assume that it is still around 50k per garrison unit.

TL;DR around 50,000.

Comment: That's the first Battle of Geonosis; the question is about the second. The link in my comment suggests millions of droids for the second battle.

Comment: It's all in the same year, read the edit.