# Total droid death in the Clone Wars

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, kill-count

In total, how many droids were killed/destroyed in the Clone Wars? I need to know so I can crunch numbers and get a kill-death ratio for clones.

Comment: A. All of them.

Comment: I'm honestly very tempted to VTC this, because there's absolutely no references I'm familiar with that even come close to answering this.  That said, even though I'm a Star Wars junkie, I'm sure there's sources I'm *not* familiar with...I just doubt there is an official answer (or even enough info for a reasonable guess).

Comment: Presumably you only want to know the number of droids destroyed by the *clones*? You'd need to know how many droids were produced over the course of the war, minus the number deactivated by Vader at the end of the war. And you'd have to somehow discount the number destroyed by Jedi. None of these numbers are going to be easy to obtain, and uncertainty in each will make the final calculation even more uncertain.

Comment: But we can get a idea of the scope of the conflict, as we know clone numbers. 200,000 + a million more soonish. The process to get a trained clone from nothing took like a decade. And at most that first attack on main enemy stronghold (that overwhelmed them) was 200,000.

Most battles/wars, when you have a decent general, do not end in massacres.

And the clones were always the clear dominate power, from my understanding.

So well under a million, likely. At most probably around the million mark, if it was a real meat grinder of a war.

Comment: I am also sure there are references somewhere of the size of individual fleets/battles.

Comment: Might be easier to answer if you asked how many survived.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski The comments on [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/72070/31936) indicate over a million droids at the first Battle of Geonosis alone, and production of one million droids per year per factory.

Comment: Ya I was reading around, and obvious they are some very contradictory numbers. That gets it facts from here (http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarsglossaryandfaq/a/Star-Wars-Faq-How-Many-Clone-Troopers-Are-There.htm)

Which states that there was millions of clones being produced per year. If we consider the movie top canon, this sounds impossible. The wiki article states there was a second factory created, but it was not producing clones till year three of the war (which I think is basically the end of the war). The original facility might of been retrofited, and maybe could have produced 1 batch.

Comment: It also states a quadrillion droids were active which is a incompletely impossible number as they could of won the war in 3 days with an army of droids per clone trooper. At that point it does not matter if there was 1 million or 10 million troopers.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski a minor point, but if you're referring in your first comment to AoTC, the cloners only state to OWKenobi that an additional million "units" were almost ready to be produced; a "unit" could refer to an individual or a group of unspecified size. So the clone army could be considerably more than several million. Unless you've found an official source that gives a more precise body count?

Comment: There is quite a bit of controversy over the number of clone and battle droids.

Comment: Are you talking about in Legends or in Canon, the numbers can be significantly different (by a few digits.)